# Python script works when run directly but not via cron job

Tags: python, cron

I have the following cron job installed:

```
0 0 * * * sh /home/pine64/finance/cron.sh >cron.log 2>&1
```

The contents of `cron.sh` are:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/pine64/finance/main.py
```

If I run `sh cron.sh` the Python script runs as expected, however, when the cron job executes it, it fails:

```
  File "/home/pine64/finance/main.py", line 17, in execute
    return self.client.place_market_order(
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cbpro/authenticated_client.py", line 393, in place_market_order
    return self.place_order(**params)
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cbpro/authenticated_client.py", line 256, in place_order
    return self._send_message('post', '/orders', data=json.dumps(params))
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cbpro/public_client.py", line 268, in _send_message
    r = self.session.request(method, url, params=params, data=data,
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 474, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 397, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 306, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 543, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cbpro/cbpro_auth.py", line 19, in __call__
    request.headers.update(get_auth_headers(timestamp, message,
  File "/home/pine64/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cbpro/cbpro_auth.py", line 28, in get_auth_headers
    hmac_key = base64.b64decode(secret_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 80, in b64decode
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data
    raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'NoneType'
```

I cannot figure out why the 1:1 same Python script works perfectly fine when I run it manually but fails when it gets run via cron. Any pointers or ideas?

Comment: Where is the `secret_key` loaded from? A file?

Comment: Could you please share argument parsing code in `main.py`

Comment: I load API keys et al from environment variables @ptts

Comment: That might actually be the culprit. Perhaps I could inline them in my cron job declaration instead?

Comment: Yes, most likely that is the reason. Cronjobs do not, by default, know about your environment variables. Check out the suggestions here: https://serverfault.com/a/337921